# Google Search Console report "Reference AMP URL is not an AMP version"

Tags: amp-html, google-search-console

I know there are simil post like this, but none of them resolve my problem.

In Search Console I've a lot of "Reference AMP URL is not an AMP version" and it show me a list of non-amp url, for example:

https://www.visittuscany.com/it/localita/poggibonsi/

in the source code you can see the amphtml meta with correct url:

The AMP Page (https://www.visittuscany.com/amp/it/poggibonsi/) is valid, I tried it in the google amp checker.

If I try to re-run the validation after few second it report the error above.

Can you help me to understand where's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem: the list of URL not valid is formed by elements extract from "amphtml" meta, so there were pages on my website with that values in the "amphtml" meta.

I thinked that search console shows me the list of pages with the error, instead it show error found on pages, but not indicate which pages contains error.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your AMP page is valid you should not worry.

Steps to take

1. Use [AMP TEST](https://search.google.com/test/amp) to see if your
   page is valid
2. Re-trigger validation inside of Google Search Console for this
   page
3. Wait few days for Google to start crawling your page again

We had a similar issue a few weeks back. We had around 2K AMP pages with this error in GSC. We took the above steps to resolve it.

From what we could find out, the problem was on the Google's end, where GSC was unable to pull through validation for the AMP pages correctly.

Here is a support [thread](https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/9557327?hl=en) if you want to read more about it.